# Употребление слова "сама" в данном контексте

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Из "Обыкновенной истории" И. А. Гончарова:

> Всё благоприятствовало ему. Кареты у подъезда не было. Тихо прошёл он
>   залу и на минуту остановился перед дверями гостиной, чтобы перевести
>   дух. Там Наденька играла на фортепиано. Дальше через комнату ***сама***
>   Любецкая сидела на диване и вязала шарф.

Сомнений нет в том, что "сама Любецкая" — это мама Наденьки. Вопрос в том, почему она обозначена словом ***"сама"***. Откуда пошла традиция характеризовать так хозяев дома? Пока писал вопрос, заглянул в Грамоту и увидел там такое значение слова "сам" (2-е) с пометкой ***"разг.- сниж."***. Хотелось бы поподробнее понять в связи с этим, насколько это действительно культурно так говорить, а также как менялась распространённость этого выражения и насколько оно популярно сейчас.

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Пока писал вопрос, заглянул в Грамоту и увидел там такое значение слова "сам" (2-е) с пометкой **"разг.- сниж."**._ === В приведённом Вами примере слово **сам** употреблено в другом значении. См.:  **II. местоим. прил. 1.** Подчёркивает, что речь идёт о данном лице или предмете; именно он и никто другой, именно оно и ничто другое. _В этом вопросе будет разбираться **сам президент**..._

Comment: А как тогда логически сделать вывод, что это мать? Почему не дочь? В этом контексте не к кому применить "именно она", на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Традиция в прошлом была такая, что дочерей, живших с родителями, называли по имени, а по фамилии называли глав семьи и их супруг.  Так что "Любецким" величали [бы] отца Наденьки, а "Любецкой" - её мать.  А если отца уже не было в живых, то вдова становилась главой дома (*я, впрочем, эту книгу не читал, так что не знаю, был ли Наденькин отец жив в это время*)

Согласно этой традиции хозяева (а дочь зачастую не считалось таковой) стояли на несколько ступеней выше даже своих детей, и заслуживали почтенного (а не просто вежливого) обращения.  Для выделения хозяев при упоминании, могли использоваться местоимения "сам", "сама", в значении (из Викисловаря)

> 2. употребляется для подчёркивания значимости, особой важности и величия лица или предмета: ◆ На другой день Самгин узнал, что Спивак допрашивал не ротмистр, а ***сам*** генерал. Максим Горький, «Жизнь Клима Самгина», Часть 2, 1928 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы) ◆ Наш незаметный Пьер смеет любить, да ещё кого, ***саму*** Ольгу Сур, первую артистку цирка, мировую знаменитость, дочь грозного и всесильного директора, страшнее и богаче которого не было никого на свете. А. И. Куприн, «Ольга Сур», 1929 г. (цитата из Библиотеки Максима Мошкова, см. Список литературы)

Comment: Спасибо, Виктор! Только в Ваших примерах есть указание на лицо и нету возможной неоднозначности толкования (генерал в примере один, Ольга тоже конкретная), именно подчёркивается величие, важность лица, нужно поставить ударение на слове сам. Кстати, об отце ничего не говорится до этого отрывка (а дальше я пока не читал).

Comment: Нет, ударение на "сам" или "сама" делать не нужно.  У Гончарова тоже нет возможности неоднозначности толкования (см. начало моего ответа).  Никого кроме матери не стали бы называть по фамилии.

Comment: Я написал только про формальную неоднозначность, которой при нашем с Вами понимании, конечно, реально нет.

Comment: Согласна с Виктором,здесь подчёркивание важности персоны. "Сам/сама" в разг.-сниж. значении употребляется самостоятельно, без фамилии: Подождём самого. Вот сам придёт и решит. Сам-то у меня мастеровитый. А здесь указание на  то, что Любецкая - самый важный человек в доме и нужный герою в данный момент.

Comment: Он же хотел просить руки её дочери, но разговор с Наденькой изменил решение.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, Людмила, спасибо!